# .net RichTextBox - Set fonts automatically

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, richtextbox, richtext

I have a .net RichTextBox which is filled with a certain report document, my application creates. This report shall then be edited by the user if desired and printed. This works so far but I want to do it a little more "human readable" by formatting certain paragraphs depending on their content automatically (e.g. red bold text for critical events in a certain section).

At the moment, i create a (big) string which is then passed to the box:

```
Dim Report as String = SubString1 & vbnewline & Substring 2 & vbnewline & .....
RTBox.Text = Report
```

My question: Is it possible, to assign different fonts/alignments/styles to the substrings, e.g. Substring 1 is right aligned and bold, substing2 is left aligned and italic and so on.

I am aware of the  SelectionFont and SelectionColor commands, but they seem to work only for a text fragment, that is currently selected in the box? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Luke

Comment: Such a feature rapidly becomes impractical when whatever the user adds or modifies still needs to have the proper font and colors.  RichTextBox is not a good programming editor.  Google ".net programming editor control" to get ahead.

Comment: Thank you Hans for this comment. I should really consider that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal from my further research.
Using RTBox.rtf = "...." instead of RTBox.Text="...." one is able to write rtf-code to the box which then displays the document well formatted.